# Error with class in python

Tags: python, oop

I've written some code that works when typed directly into the interpreter, but fails when called.

Here's some code (there's a lot here to make it reproducible):

```
import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
data = sm.datasets.longley.load()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.exog, columns=data.exog_name)
y = data.endog
df['intercept'] = 1.
olsresult = sm.OLS(y, df).fit()
olsresult2 = sm.OLS(y, df[['GNP', 'UNEMP', 'ARMED']]).fit()
olsresult3 = sm.OLS(y, df[['GNP', 'POP', 'ARMED', 'YEAR']]).fit()
models = [olsresult, olsresult2, olsresult3]

class generateTable(object):

    def __init__(self, output, models, center='True', parens='se', var_names=None):
        self.output = output
        self.models = models
        self.center = center
        self.parens = parens
        self.var_names = var_names

    def createModel(self):
        results = []
        for model in self.models:
            params = dict(model.params)
            bse = dict(model.bse)
            pvals = dict(model.pvalues)
            results.append(dict((k, [params[k], bse[k], pvals[k]]) for k in sorted(params.iterkeys())))

        tempModel = {}
        for key in results[0]:
            tempModel[key] = [results[0][key]]

        for model in results[1:len(results)]:
            for key in model:
                if key not in tempModel:
                    tempModel[key] = [['', '', '']]

        for i in range(1,len(results)):
            diff = set(tempModel) - set(results[i])
            for key in results[i]:
                tempModel[key].append(results[i][key])
            for key in diff:
                tempModel[key].append(['','',''])


        if self.var_names == None:
            self.inputModel = tempModel
        elif type(self.var_names) == list:
            replace = self.var_names
            newResults = []
            resultsList = sorted(tempModel.iteritems())
            for item in resultsList:
                newVar = list(item)
                newResults.append(newVar)
            for i in range(len(newResults)):
                newResults[i][0] = replace[i]
                self.inputModel = dict(newResults)
```

Whenever I try to run the script I receive an error `AttributeError: 'generateTable' object has no attribute 'model'`. IPython points out the line `bse = dict(model.bse)`. Again, this works when I run it interactively (i.e. chunk by chunk, no class), but when I import the file and try to run it I receive the error.

**EDIT:**

1) How is it being created?

```
import project

a = project.generateTable('/path/to/test.tex', models, center='True', parens='se', var_names=None)
a.createModel()
```

2) The whole traceback is:

```
In [26]: a.createModel()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/path/to/project/<ipython-input-26-6774b6d1804c> in <module>()
----> 1 a.createModel()

/path/to/project/project.py in createModel(self)
     39         for model in models:
     40             params = dict(model.params)
---> 41             bse = dict(model.bse)
     42             pvals = dict(model.pvalues)
     43             results.append(dict((k, [params[k], bse[k], pvals[k]]) for k in sorted(params.iterkeys())))
```

3) I'm going to try changing the var name `model` to something else.

4) Sorry about the syntax error. Thank you, asmeurer, for the fix.

**EDIT 2:**

3 above (changing the var name `model` to something else) didn't work.

### EDIT 3:

It works now. Here's the latest code:

```
def __init__(self, output, models, center='True', parens='se', var_names=None):
    self.output = output
    self.models = models
    self.center = center
    self.parens = parens
    self.var_names = var_names

def createModel(self):
    results = []
    for test_model in self.models:
        params = dict(test_model.params)
        bse = dict(test_model.bse)
        pvals = dict(test_model.pvalues)
        results.append(dict((k, [params[k], bse.get(k), pvals.get(k)]) for k in sorted(params.iterkeys())))
```

The only thing that's different is model in the for loop has been changed to test_model. I tried that before and it didn't work, so I'm not quite sure how it happend.

Thanks everyone for the help! And if anyone could point how why this change got rid of that particular error message it'd be greatly appreciated. I'd like to actually know what I was doing instead of just moving on and accepting it.

Comment: Could you show how you are creating the generateTable objects / calling the createModel methods?

Comment: I made what I believe was the correct fix.  Please correct it if I was wrong.

Comment: Paste the whole error traceback here, it must point to the exact line where you have problme

Comment: There might be a name conflict somewhere else in your code. Try changing the variable name `model` to, say, `currModel`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have actually tried it before finishing the edit.

Comment: did you try to edit traceback? why?

Comment: The only thing I edited in the traceback was the path to the file because it had some information that I didn't want to be on the net in it.

Comment: Your stack trace shows the line `for model in models` yet your code seems to have `for model in self.models`. To further complicate things, you say your error is complaining about the attribute `model` (without the trailing "s"). Are you certain everything you are reporting is accurate? Something seems very wrong about the way you are describing tne problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I should probably be more clear with my edits. I'm trying things as people suggested them and so I probably got the error and code mixed up.

Comment: @user1074057: if you want help, you need to be precise in the error message you report, and precise in the code. Don't keep adding "edit" sections, simply rewrite your question as accurately as possible. If you say you are getting error A with this code, but are actually getting error B with some subtly different code, there is no way we can help you. Copy and paste the precise error message, and the exact line of code that is causing he error, at a minimum.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry, I will be more diligent moving forward.

Comment: (posted after you "edit 3") judging by the original error message you posted, it's probably that you had `for model in self.model` rather than `...in self.models`. It's hard to say for sure because your question is very confusing, with conflicting information.

Comment: @BryanOakley, yes, sorry about that again. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see an error like `AttributeError: 'xxx' object has no attribute 'yyy'`, that can only mean one thing: you have an object of type `xxx` and you are trying to access the attribute `.yyy` but the object doesn't have that attribute. First rule of debugging: assume the error is telling the truth.

To put it in concrete terms, somewhere you are doing something like:

```
a = project.generateTable()
...
foo=a.model
```

When I look at the code you posted, I see nowhere where the attribute `model` is defined for the class `generateTable`. Do you think you are setting it somewhere? Either you aren't (which seems to be the case), or you are but you are setting it at some point after you are first trying to access it.

Comment: `model` is from the for loop: for `model in self.models:` and self.models is defined in the __init__ function: `self.models = models` where models is defined in the `a = project.generatedTable('/path/to/test.tex', models)`.

Comment: @user1074057: I am aware of that, but that doesn't explain the error message you report. Like my answer says, when you get an "object has no attribute" error, it almost always means you are doing `x.y` where `y` doesn't exist. If the error were on the loop, you would get an "unbound lcal variable" error instead of what you say you get. Nowhere in the code you posted do you assign `self.model` or `a.model`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to refer to the variables you defined in the global scope of `project` as members of the `project` namespace. In the code, where you call

```
import project

a = project.generateTable('/path/to/test.tex', models, center='True', parens='se', var_names=None)
a.createModel()
```

...the variable `models` isn't bound to anything. It's a null value, the object attribute doesn't get bound when you call `_init_`, and you get the Python equivalent of a nullref. In order to use it, you'd need to write it as `project.models`. (Or you could write `from project import models` at the top.)

UPDATE: Sorry, looking at your update, it looks like there's a discrepancy between the error message and the code. The error message says you were iterating over "models" instead of "self.models". You said you'd tried changing the variable name before and it didn't work; I'm betting that you left out the "self.*" qualifier. This would have caused you to use a different "models" variable.

Comment: I think if this were the case there would be a different error message than the one that was reported.

Comment: Maybe, but if the code he's posting is the code he's using, then that is a problem. (And if we follow the error message alone, note that it mentions "models", not "self.models" as the variable being iterated over, which leads into naming issues as well.)